# Trying to make my sprite jump when someone taps on screen using onTouchEvent(MotionEvent), but don't know how this method is supposed to be used?

Tags: android, touch, 2d, sprite

Right now all I have in my game is a sprite that moves from the left of the screen to the right. I'm trying to make it jump whenever the screen is touched, so I added this class:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;

 public class TouchScreen extends Activity {
 private Player p;
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    int i = e.getAction();

    switch (i) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // When your finger touches the screen
        p.jump();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        // When your finger stop touching the screen

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // When your finger moves around the screen

        break;
    }

    return false;
    }
  }
```

Now I'm trying to call this method in `Player.update()` (Player is the class of the sprite) but I don't know what to pass into `onTouchEvent()`. I basically want "if screen is tapped make player jump" (by calling `Player.jump()`), any ideas?

Comment: You have to set this touchlistner to your SurfaceView (or whatever you're using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that `onTouchEvent` overrides the original method in `Activity`. You should also call `super.onTouchEvent(e);` at the end since the method you're overriding may need to execute.

```
@Overrides
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
int i = e.getAction();

switch (i) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    // When your finger touches the screen
    p.jump();
    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    // When your finger stop touching the screen

    break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    // When your finger moves around the screen

    break;
}

return super.onTouchEvent(e);
}
```

You don't explicitly call `onTouchEvent`, this should be called by the system when the activity is touched. You've got the `p.jump();` in the correct place though!